# Running TestNG unit test in Eclipse ignores latest changes

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testng

I have a maven-based Java project, which contains many unit tests.  These unit tests take a long time to execute, so I'm trying to execute only a specific test class via the TestNG Eclipse plugin.

[image]

Running the test the first time works as expected, but if I make any changes to the test class and try to re-run it, I get the same result as the previous run.  Basically, my changes to the test class are ignored and the test is executed using a previously compiled test class.

Comment: Have you tried running using testng.xml by `<class>` tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project had several unrelated errors (visible under the Problems view).  Once those errors were resolved, the test class was automatically compiled and changes were picked up in subsequent executions of the unit tests.